# getClusters () function is not working

Tags: google-maps, markerclusterer

According to the documentation - correct way to get all clusters for a markerCluster is to call getClusters() function.

I create markerCluster:

```
   markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer($scope.map, $scope.markers, mcOptions);
```

Then, when markers are clustered, am getting the total number of clusters (per viewport) and wan't to get Clusters and then access markers for each cluster. (count clusters on change the map)

```
 $scope.map.addListener('idle', countClusters);

        function countClusters() {
            console.log('get clusters number', markerCluster.getTotalClusters());
            console.log('clusters', markerCluster.getClusters());
        }
```

the result is 'get clusters number' - 2; but for getClusters() - got an error - **markerCluster.getClusters is not a function.**

Can't find out the reason :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is related to the markercluster.js version, fixed with changing to

```
<script src="https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.1.2/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```